# How do I resize buttons in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I resize buttons in tkinter?

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.minsize(200, 200)

b = Button(win, text="Click Me")
b.pack()
```

I don't know how to resize buttons in tkinter so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the height and width parameters:

```
Button(win, text="Click Me", height = 100, width = 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `height` and `width` keywords:

```
Button(win, text="Click Me", height = 100, width = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

````
import tkinter.font as tkFont
    
win= tk.Tk()
win.minsize("400x200")

    
b = tk.Button(win, text="Click Me", width=20, height=30)

b.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

app.mainloop()```

You can adjust the `Button(width=)` and `Button(height=)` according to your needs.
````